# How to disable cool fonts in Android EditText?

Tags: android

If I set cool font on my phone keyboard, the characters I enter in editText are not the default grid font, which makes it difficult for me to get the string to determine what it actually means

ex:
The string I entered after setting the cool font is ① ② ③.
The string I got through getText().toString() is not equal to 123.
So now I want to prohibit edittext from being able to input cool fonts. Is there a way for edittext to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent a keyboard from sending anything it wants to into an edit text.  What you can do is set a TextWatcher on it and change it back to something without those characters if you don't like them.

That said, I wouldn't worry about this too much.  What you did wasn't setting a font on your keyboard-  keyboards can't type in fonts.  What it can do is send other characters that map to letters in the font your edit text is using.  This would be the equivalent of sending emojis.  Nobody is going to do this and think your app is broken, they'll do it, see it doesn't work, and change their keyboard back.  I'd just examine the text before using it and pop up a warning if it holds invalid data.